# shell script if folder exist has incorrect result

Tags: shell

I have this shell script, and the folder does exist, but it always have no as result?

```
#!/bin/bash

FOLDER=/Library/Application\ Support/ESET/esets

if [ -d “$FOLDER” ];
then
echo yes
else
echo no
fi
```

thanks!

Comment: The quotes look odd - try replacing them using the keyboard rather than cut and paste.

Comment: Non-English keyboard? Use `"$FOLDER"` instead.

Comment: thanks  @CodeGnome , I am using English keyboard..mmmmm...strange...but after I copy yours...it worked!

Comment: thanks @user2182349...that is the issue.... I am using external logitech keyboard..maybe that's why...

Answer (score 0):

> if [ -d “$FOLDER” ];

The type of quote marks you're using are not valid for the shell. Use `"$FOLDER"` instead.